# TextView cutting off content

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView within a ScrollView all wrapped in a LinearLayout and the end of the TextView is getting cutoff (multiple lines).

This is the XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"            
            android:text="" 
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView is cutting off regardless of whether the pane scrolls or not and it's driving me mad! Any help?!

Comment: "... and the end of the TextView is getting cutoff (multiple lines)."? Do you mean the end (right) or the bottom?

Comment: At the bottom. It's about 40 - 50 words, not just the last word!

Comment: I tried your code and no text got cutoff for me. I think there might be other conflicting elements. Post your complete XML layout. You can also try using the `paddingBottom=10dp` for your `TextView` inside `ScrollView`. See if it works.

Comment: Abhi, it is a fragment added to the ViewPager.

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

... AppBarLayout and TabLayout removed to meet comment length restriction!!!

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">//try this
```

if this doesnt solve the problem then:-

also you can try using ScrollView as a parent view.No need of that Linear layout if it just contains a single child(TextView)

Comment: Hi, sadly neither of those options make any difference! The text that is to be displayed is added to the view is added in C# via:

    tvDescription.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(trackInfo.Description + "<br />", FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy);

Answer (score 0):

Update. I 'fixed' the issue by changing the type of the fragment to work as a RecyclerFragment. Which when the fragment is added to the rest of the structure stops the cut-off!

I've inherited this app mid-development and the hand-over was...finish this app and fix the bugs, so I am finding my way through wearing a blindfold!

Thanks anyway!